# YetAnotherForum Upgrade encountering a SQL DB issue

Tags: sql, upgrade, yaf

We've been using yaf since 2001 or 2002.

The version of our forums is 1.7 with more than 2.5 million users registered, which makes for a lot of data...

I've made a copy of the actual DB and I'm trying to upgrade this installation to version 2.1.1, but I get a SQL error on the mssql/tables.sql file when trying to upgrade:

> FILE: mssql/tables.sql
>
> ERROR: The index
>   '_dta_index_yaf_Message_9_757577737__K2_K1_K12_K6_4_5_7_8_10_11' is
>   dependent on column 'IP'. ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN IP failed because
>   one or more objects access this column.
>
> STATEMENT: if exists (select top 1 1 from sys.columns where
>   object_id=object_id('[dbo].[yaf_Message]'Wink and name='IP' and
>   precision < 39) begin alter table [dbo].[yaf_Message] alter column
>   [IP] varchar(39) not null end
>
> YAF.Classes.Data.LegacyDb.system_initialize_executescripts(String
>   script, String scriptFile, Boolean useTransactions) +1540
>   YAF.Core.Services.InstallUpgradeService.ExecuteScript(String
>   scriptFile, Boolean useTransactions) +188
>   YAF.Core.Services.InstallUpgradeService.UpgradeDatabase(Boolean
>   fullText, Boolean upgradeExtensions) +205
>   YAF.Install._default.Wizard_NextButtonClick(Object sender,
>   WizardNavigationEventArgs e) +1559
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object source,
>   EventArgs e) +584 System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object
>   source, EventArgs args) +84
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +3804

Do I have to modify some table fields?

The other solution I have is to import manually every single user, forum, etc., but it would take quite some time, so I'm really looking to let the install upgrade the DB automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could in theory do the following;

1. Backup DB (again)
2. Script the index to a new window.
3. Drop the index.
4. Apply the update.
5. Check the data does not have nulls and fix if required.
6. Recreate the index.

Comment: i'll try that, it'll take some time since we have more than 2.5M users